# How to get values of multiple input in one string by ".val()" using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I want to get the values of all input at once using one `.val()` function in jQuery.

```
$("#txt1").val();
$("#txt2").val();
$("#txt3").val();
```

Instead of this I want to write the below code

```
$("#txt1, #txt2, #txt3").val();
```

Comment: This isn't possible. The `val()` method can only return one value from one element at a time

Comment: can you tell us your purpose why you do not want to use *each* here ?

Answer (score 7):

Use [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) to convert selected input to value of them and then use [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to convert array result to string.

```js
var values = $("#txt1, #txt2, #txt3").map(function(){
  return this.value;
}).get().join(" ");
console.log(values)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txt1" value="a" />
<input type="text" id="txt2" value="b" />
<input type="text" id="txt3" value="c" />
```

Comment: I guess this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var arr= $("input").map(function(){
  return $(this).val();
}).get();
console.log(arr)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="1">
<input type="text" value="11">
<input type="text" value="11">
```

You need to loop through them try using `.map()`